# Conditionally providing overload of comparizon operator if template parameter provides it too

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have a templated class

```
template <typename T>
class SometimesComparable
{
public:
  T x1;
  T x2;
  // Other functionally provided unconditionally
  // ...
  // To be provided only if T provides operator<
  // bool operator<(SometimesComparable const & other) const 
  // {
  //   return x1 < other.x1 && x2 < other.x2;
  // }
};
```

that should provide `bool operator<()` if and only if its template parameter also provides `bool operator<()`

I have read similar questions/answers that use SFINAE but there must be something I didn't understand because I didn't manage to adapt the idea to this case.

Imitating those answers I have a class

```
template <typename T>
class HasLessThan
{
private:
    typedef char YesType[1];
    typedef char NoType[2];

    template <typename C> static YesType& test( decltype(&C::operator<)     );
    template <typename C> static NoType& test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(YesType) };
};
```

to detect, using its method `test` via its member `value`, whether a class `T` provides `operator<`.

Inside the `SometimesComparable` class I am defining

```
typename std::enable_if<HasLessThan<T>::value, bool>::type
operator<(ConditionalMethodProvided &other)
{
    return x1 < other.x1 && x2 < other.x2;
}
```

Then, for testing, for a use that works I have a class

```
class TypeWithLessThan
{
public:
  int x;
  TypeWithLessThan(int x) : x(x) {};
  bool operator<(TypeWithLessThan &other) {return x < other.x;};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ConditionalMethodProvided C(TypeWithLessThan(2), TypeWithLessThan(3));
    ConditionalMethodProvided D(TypeWithLessThan(5), TypeWithLessThan(7));
    std::cout << (C < D) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Question part:** This is fine. Now, what I am missing is how should be the implementation such that

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ConditionalMethodProvided C(2, 3);
    ConditionalMethodProvided D(5, 7);
    std::cout << (C < D) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

also compiles successfully.

I tried adding to `SometimesComparable` a friend method

```
friend
typename std::enable_if<HasLessThan<T>::value, bool>::type
operator<(ConditionalMethodProvided & a1, ConditionalMethodProvided &a2)
{
    return a1.x1 < a2.x1 && a1.x2 < a2.x2;
};
```

Having both the first `operator<` and the friend one, creates an ambiguous overload, not having it causes the comparison of `ConditionalMethodProvided<int, int>` to not compile.

I would like both `int` and `TypeWithLessThan` to work.

---

**Edit:**

The code in a single block.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class HasLessThan
{
private:
    typedef char YesType[1];
    typedef char NoType[2];

    template <typename C> static YesType& test( decltype(&C::operator<) );
    template <typename C> static NoType& test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(YesType) };
};

template <typename T>
class ConditionalMethodProvided
{
public:
    T x1;
    T x2;
    ConditionalMethodProvided(T&& a1, T&& a2) : x1(a1), x2(a2) {};

    // This and the next method may not be needed at the same time.
    typename std::enable_if<HasLessThan<T>::value, bool>::type
    operator<(ConditionalMethodProvided &other)
    {
        return x1 < other.x1 && x2 < other.x2;
    };

    template <typename U,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T>, bool> = true>
    auto operator< (ConditionalMethodProvided<U> & oth)
        -> decltype( std::declval<U>() < std::declval<U>(), bool{} )
        { return x1 < oth.x1 && x2 < oth.x2; }
};

class TypeWithLessThan
{
public:
  int x;
  TypeWithLessThan(int x) : x(x) {};
  bool operator<(TypeWithLessThan &other) {return x < other.x;};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // The question is how to to make the next two types, int and TypewithLessThan both make the templated class ConditionalMethodProvided to provide the operator< method.
    ConditionalMethodProvided C(TypeWithLessThan(2),     TypeWithLessThan(3));
    ConditionalMethodProvided D(TypeWithLessThan(5),     TypeWithLessThan(7));
    std::cout << (C < D) << std::endl;

    ConditionalMethodProvided E(2,3);
    ConditionalMethodProvided F(5,7);
    std::cout << (E < F) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about as follows ?

```
template <typename T>
class SometimesComparable
 {
   public:
      T x1;
      T x2;

      template <typename U, 
                std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T>, bool> = true>
      auto operator< (SometimesComparable<U> const & oth)
         -> decltype( x1 < oth.x1, bool{} )
       { return x1 < oth.x1 && x2 < oth.x2; }
 };
```

I mean... if you want SFINAE enable/disable a method, you have to make the method a template one, so

```
  template <typename U>
  bool operator< (SometimesComparable<U> const & oth)
   { /* something */ }
```

but I suppose you want that `U` and `T` are the same type, so you can impose this throug `std::enable_if_t`

```
  template <typename U, 
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T>, bool> = true>
  bool operator< (SometimesComparable<U> const & oth)
   { /* something */ }
```

Now you have to SFINAE enable the operator iff (if and only if) you can write `x1 < oth.x1` (when the operator is defined for `U`) so, using `auto`, trailing return type and `decltype()`, you can write

```
  auto operator< (SometimesComparable<U> const & oth)
     -> decltype( x1 < oth.x1, bool{} )
   { /* something */ }
```

or also simply `decltype( x1 < oth.x1 )` if you're sure that `x1 < oth.x1` gives a `bool` value.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but when I use it (as only method in the class) the case for `C < D` with `C` and `D` of type `SometimesComparable<TypeWithLessThan>` the compiler says that no version of `operator<` matches. When used for `int`s it does work. But I cannot add both versions (the one that worked for me and yours) because mine gives error with `int`.

Comment: @conditionalMethod - Sorry but isn't completely clear for me. Please, can you add in your question a minimal but complete example?

Comment: Will do. The code already posted is complete, although broken with words in between because the page requested to have more words. Let me gather them all in a single code block.

Comment: Added it. It contains both the version of the method that I had, and your suggestion. If you comment out my version and the instances of `ConditionalMethodProvided<TypeWithLessThan, TypeWithLessThan>` in the main, it compiles. If instead you comment out the instances of `ConditionalMethodProvided<int, int>` in the main it compiles. But the use of both types is what I haven't managed to make work.

Comment: @conditionalMethod - not clear what you exactly want, anyway... your version cannot works because isn't a template operator; if you want that SFINAE works, you have to write something as follows: `template <typename U = T> std::enable_if_t<HasLessThan_v<U>, bool> operator<(ConditionalMethodProvided &other) { return x1 < other.x1 && x2 < other.x2; }`. Observe that `HasLessThan_v` check `U`, the template type of the method, not `T`.

Comment: @conditionalMethod - not clear to me if you want the `int` enable the operator; anyway, with `HasLessThan`, you check (see `decltype(&C::operator<)`) if `T` is a **class** (or struct) with a method `operator<` enabled. So `int` result without less, because isn't a class and the `operator<` is written in the language and isn't a method of the class.

Comment: Oh, wow. Now it works by making my version a method with an additional template parameter as you said. I need to digest it now to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can write this in C++20 concepts:

```
    // To be provided only if T provides operator<
    auto operator<(SometimesComparable const & other) const -> bool
        requires requires(T a, T b) {
            {a < b} -> bool;
        }
    {
        return x1 < other.x1 && x2 < other.x2;
    }
```

Comment: @conditionalMethod soon, in C++20. There is experimental implementation in clang: https://godbolt.org/z/e-TDk4 and gcc also has concepts implemented with `-fconcepts`, but afaik it's an old proposal, not the standard draft one.